# Spark Results from two tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two files/tables as below

```
File1: 
101,10,20 
102,30,40 
103,50,60
```

and

```
File2: 
101,10,20 
104,70,80 
103,50,55
```

and after comparing both files I need to create new file as:

```
File3:
102,30,40,D
104,70,80,I
103,50,55,U
```

where `D` is "Deleted", `I` is "Inserted" and `U` is "Updated".

I have tried with RDD `subtract` and also SparkSQL, but in Spark 1.x has limitations on sub-queries.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want as result? 
Is not clear if you want the tuple not in common between two dataframes or something else.

Comment: @pheeleeppoo, basically i want to capture the data change by comparing two files, file2 is recent file. as updated above i want get new file that contains changed rows with respective flag and ignore any unchanged row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the below. here I have two dataframes df1 and df2. df1 is the primary dataset with key column a1 which is being compared with the secondary dataset df2 with key column b1. so if the fields a2,a3 and b2,b3 of a key are the same then those records are ignored.

- the records are flagged as D if the key exists in df1 and not in df2.
- the records are flagged as I if the key exists in df2 and not in df1.
- the records are flagged as U if the key exists in both df1 and df2 but the value fields are different.

below is the code snippet.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

input1 = [[101,10,20], [102,30,40], [103,50,60]]
input2 = [[101,10,20], [104,70,80], [103,50,55]]

df1 = sc.parallelize(input1).toDF(schema= StructType([StructField("a1", IntegerType(), False),StructField("a2", IntegerType(), False),StructField("a3", IntegerType(), False)]))
df2 = sc.parallelize(input2).toDF(schema=StructType([StructField("b1", IntegerType(), False),StructField("b2", IntegerType(), False),StructField("b3", IntegerType(), False)]))

joindf = df1.join(df2, [df1.a1 == df2.b1], 'outer').filter(((df1.a2 != df2.b2) | (df1.a3 != df2.b3)) | df1.a1.isNull() | df2.b1.isNull())

def check_row(a1, b1):
    if not a1:
        return 'D'
    elif not b1:
        return 'I'
    else:
        return 'U'

flagger = udf(check_row)
joindf.withColumn("flag", flagger(joindf.a1, joindf.b1)).select(F.when(joindf.a1.isNull(), joindf.b1).otherwise(joindf.a1).alias('a1'),F.when(joindf.a2.isNull(), joindf.b2).otherwise(joindf.a2).alias('a2'),F.when(joindf.a3.isNull(), joindf.b3).otherwise(joindf.a3).alias('a3'),'flag').show()
+---+---+---+----+
| a1| a2| a3|flag|
+---+---+---+----+
|103| 50| 60|   U|
|102| 30| 40|   I|
|104| 70| 80|   D|
+---+---+---+----+
```

or if you prefer spark-sql use the below snippet.

```
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df1, 'df1')
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df2, 'df2')
sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT 
CASE WHEN a1 IS NULL THEN b1 ELSE a1 END as c1,
CASE WHEN a2 IS NULL THEN b2 ELSE a1 END as c2,
CASE WHEN a3 IS NULL THEN b3 ELSE a1 END as c3,
CASE 
   WHEN a1 IS NULL THEN 'I' 
   WHEN b1 is NULL THEN 'D' 
   ELSE 'U' END as flag
FROM df1 FULL OUTER JOIN df2 ON df1.a1 = df2.b1
WHERE (df1.a2 <> df2.b2 or df1.a3 <> df2.b3) or (df1.a1 is null) or (df2.b1 is null)
""").show()

+---+---+---+----+
| c1| c2| c3|flag|
+---+---+---+----+
|103|103|103|   U|
|102|102|102|   D|
|104| 70| 80|   I|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible idea could be grouping both RDDs by your desiderated key using [**keyBy**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#keyBy) function and then apply different operations to calculate *D*, *I*, *U*.

- *D* : using [**subtractByKey**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#subtractByKey) function to calculate elements in *file1* not in *file2*;
- *I* : the same [**subtractByKey**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#subtractByKey) function to calculate elements in *file2* not in *file1*;
- *U* : using [**join**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#join) function to calculate elements (key!) in commun between *file1* and *file2*.

Remember that join function will operate with key element in commun. So in your example (101,10,20) will be as result of the join too. You have to filter this result to obtain just keys with changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think we may need to change the code slightly for spark sql to include update condition.

```
sqlContext.sql("""    
SELECT 

CASE when a1 IS NULL then b1 ELSE a1 END as c1,

CASE when a2 IS NULL then b2 
     when a1 = b1 then b2 
     else a2 END as c2,

CASE when a3 IS NULL then b3 
     when a1 = b1 then b3
     else a3 END as c3,

CASE 
   when a1 IS NULL then 'I' 
   when b1 is NULL then 'D' 
   ELSE 'U' END as flag

FROM df1 FULL OUTER JOIN df2 ON df1.a1 = df2.b1

WHERE (df1.a2 <> df2.b2 or df1.a3 <> df2.b3) or (df1.a1 is null) or (df2.b1 is null)
""").show()
```